# Postgres. Concatenate fields without fixed length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns (A and B) on table 1, and I want to concatenate them into another column (C) only if the beginning of B is not A, and if that is not the case, just copy B into C.
The key point here is that A and B do not have a fixed length, so I don't think I can use left(), since it needs a specific length.
For example:

```
ID        A                            B 
1          5                          48721
2         98                          98555
3         98                            136
4        841                     8417740313
5        841                         133889
```

In this case, column C should include:

1. For ID=1: 548721
2. For ID=2: 98555
3. For ID=3: 98136
4. For ID=4: 8417740313
5. For ID=5: 841133889

I was trying:

```
UPDATE 1
SET C = B
WHERE LEFT (B) = A
UPDATE 1
SET C = concat(A,B)
WHERE LEFT(B) <> A
```

But it doesn't work, since I need to give left() a fixed length. What would you guys do?

Comment: Columns' data types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
UPDATE t
    SET C = (CASE WHEN B LIKE A || '%' THEN B ELSE A || B END);
```

That is, you can use `LIKE` for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

```
update table 
set col_c = col_a||substr(col_b,length(col_a))
where 
substr(col_b,1,length(col_a))=col_a;
```

Step2:

```
update table 
set col_c = col_a||col_b
where 
substr(col_b,1,length(col_a))<>col_a;
```

you can try this and let us know, 
the earlier given solution is also correct; but what if the same eg: 98 in col_a is present in the middle of col_b instead of in the start ?